# pass parameters from entity to query_builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a entity

```
Product:
  name # string
  country # entity
  categories #entity many-many
```

I have a form for that entity

ProductType:
  name
  categories

now i need filter categories by country but i dont wanna show a country parameter when i build the form I do

```
//...
$entity = new Entity\Product();
$entity->setCountry($this->getUser()->getProfile()->getCountry());
$form = $this->createForm(new Form\ProductType(), $entity);

return array('form' => $form->createView());
```

i want filter the categories by country in the ProductType class, how can achieve this?.

**How i can pass $country value to query builder?**

```
//...
->add('categories', 'entity', array(
  'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBulder('c');
  }
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the `options` array you can pass to a form class.
Add this to your FormType:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'country' => null
    ));
}
```

then call the `FormType` like this:

```
$this->createForm(new Form\ProductType(), $entity, array(
    'country' => $country
));
```

And access the `$country` in your `buildForm` method like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $country = $options['country'];
```

From there on you could build you own [queryBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) to select only the products you need.

**Edit:**
For accessing the `$country` variable in the queryBuilder you should use the [`use` statement](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php). It would look like this:

```
->add('categories', 'entity', array(
   'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
   'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($country) {
       // here you can use the $country variable in your anonymous function.
       return $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
       }
    )
)
```

Comment: i build my solution but with $options['data'] that holds the entity event $options['country']. thx for the idea